# string replacement

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, localization

I have leftmenu.xml for displaying a Telerik menu, and I need to convert Text from XML which is displayed as a leftmenu into resources.

This is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<PanelItems>
  <PanelItem Text="sample" NavigateUrl="../Default.aspx?id=menu" />
  <PanelItem Text="sample2" NavigateUrl="../Default.aspx? 
        id=;category=sample2">
  <!--  -->
  <PanelItem Text="Products" NavigateUrl="../Default.aspx?id=sample3"/>
```

Here I need to convert Txt means Dashboard, sample3, Products, etc.

Comment: i googled but i didnt get any solution for this

Comment: why did you delete the question? I will rollback to the previous version for now, otherwise the answer makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create different sitemap files (one per language) containing the menu entries. Then assign the sitemap file for the current language to the telerik menu control.

See the following [online demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/menu/examples/programming/declarativedatasources/defaultcs.aspx) for an example.